# Походження фразеологізму "цур його"

Tags: етимологія, фразеологізми

Часто вживається такий  фразеологізм, як ***"цур тобі"***. На сайті [Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/search.html) знайшла лише значення слова ***"цур"***.

**Великий тлумачний словник (ВТС) сучасної української мови**

> ***[ЦУР](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53414/1015721.html)*** виг. , розм. Уживається для заборони торкатися чого-небудь, брати, привласнювати що-небудь, робити щось (за старовини
>   в заклинаннях, тепер перев. в іграх).
>
> || Вигук, яким скріплюють яку-небудь умову, домовленість і т. ін.
>   (перев. в іграх).
>
> || кому, чому. Вигук, що вживається, щоб висловити невдоволення ким-,
>   чим-небудь, несхвалення чогось.
>
> || Уживається при бажанні позбутися, не згадувати кого-, чого-небудь,
>   відвернути щось (перев. з част. хай, нехай).
>
> ***Цур тобі та (і) пек тобі*** — а) виражає побажання позбутися кого-, чого-небудь, не мати справи з кимсь, чимсь; б) уживається, щоб
>   висловити невдоволення ким-, чим-небудь.

Цікавить, яке походження має даний фразеологізм? У Словопедії, на жаль, немає.

Answer (score 5):

Є польська, грецька, чуваська, давньоскандинавська версії. А також, що "цур" походить від "цурка", тобто палиця.

Докладніше у [етимологічному словнику української мови](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/978-966-00-0197-8/978-966-00-0197-8.pdf):

> **цур¹** «вигук закляття від чогось»,
> *цур-цура́* «тс.»,
> [*цура́ха*] «цур Г; анафема Пі»,
> [*цура́чка*] «цур»,
> [*цура́ти*] «сахатися, відчужуватися»,
> [цура́ть] «займати або привласнювати щось, вигукуючи першим: “Цур, моє”» Чабаненко,
> *цура́тися* «тс., відчужуватися»,
> [_зацура́ти] «лишити, кинути»,
> [одцу́р] «зречення» Пі,
> ст. *цуратися*;
> — р. *чур*,
> бр. *цур*, [*чур*],
> п. *cur* «чорт» (з укр.);
> — задовільної етимології не має;
> пов'язується зі словом *цу́рка* «палиця (для відганяння ворожої сили)» (Преобр. ІІ, вып. последний 81–82)
> або може розглядатися як символічне дерев'яне зображення далекого предка (духа-охоронця дому),
> тоді вигуки *цур*, *цур-цура́* є зверненнями до цього духа, прикликанням його,
> пор. припущення зв'язку зі словами *пра́щур* (Желтов ФЗ 1876/4, 37; Никальский ФЗ 1891/4-5, 11) і *чорт* (Bern. І 164),
> з гр. *ϰύριος* «пан, господь» (Зеленин ІІ 93);
> гіпотези про запозичення р. *чур* з чув. tšar (*чар*) «тримай, спиняй, стій» (Gauthiot MSL 16, 89), дсканд. Туг «бог війни» (Погодин ЖСт. 20, 427) менш прийнятні.
> — Фасмер IV 385–386; Лукінова. З архаїчної лексики //Київське Полісся (К., 1989, 79–83). — Див. ще **цу́ра́**.
>
> [**цур²**] (у вислові *цуром врагу в очі глянь*) Нед; — очевидно, пов’язане з *цур*, *цу́ра* (в значенні «дух-охоронець дому»). — Див. ще **цу́ра́**.

Answer (score 2):

[Світ фразеологізмів](https://pidruchniki.com/2015082666419/kulturologiya/tsur_yomu#740) та [тут](http://filologukr.ucoz.ru/publ/skrinka_cikavinok_dlja_uchniv/filologichni_cikavinki/pro_frazeologizm_cur_jomu/35-1-0-408) подають таке пояснення походження даного фразеологізму:

> ***Цур йому*** *Цуром* називали давнє слов'янське божество, яке охороняло земельні межі. Часто на межах забивали дерев'яні стовпчики,
>   на яких був зображений Цур. Ці місця слов'яни вважали священними. Тоді
>   й з'явилося слово ***"цуратися"*** — обходити священне місце.
>
> Вислів ***"цур йому"*** виражав побажання кари Цура за поганий вчинок:
>   ***"Цур йому і віддячить"***. У сучасній мові цей фразеологізм означає незадоволення чимось, несхвалення, бажання позбутися когось.

[Жайворонок В. В. Знаки української етнокультури: Словник-довідник. — К.: Довіра, 2006. — С. 632.](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/zhaivoronok_znaky_ukrainskoi_etnokultury/%D1%86%D1%83%D1%80)

> ***Цур*** = Чур — у дохристиянських віруваннях — як і Пек (див.), можливо,
>   божество війни, бійок, кривавих сутичок, кровопролиття, всілякої біди,
>   тому й досі насилаємо комусь біду: ***«Цур тобі, пек тобі!»*** або кажемо
>   так, сахаючись, і відходимо, віддаляємося від когось, чогось,
>   цураємося (пор. ще: «Хай йому цур!»); *за версією І. Огієнка*, навпаки,
>   це домовий бог, що оберігав родину, господу, майно, і звідси, можливо,
>   [від]цуратися, тобто «покинути (кидати) свої родові межі, забути
>   (забувати) родину, когось близького, рідного чи щось близьке, рідне»;
>   кажуть: «Хоч лайся, та тільки не цурайся»; на це саме можуть вказувати
>   й вислови: «Цур та пек лихим очам!», «Цур нас та й далі од нас!»; ***Цур
>   (Чур, старосл. Щур)*** — це, можливо, обоготворений предок (звідси
>   пра́щур); на користь домового бога може бути й повір’я, що він любить
>   жити в цурі (чурі), тобто цурці, якою розпалюють піч, і тим самим
>   охороняє домашнє вогнище; так чи інакше, численні народні вислови зі
>   словом цур позначено енантіосемією, тобто як позитивним значенням
>   слова (відгомін бога-захисника), так і значенням негативним (відгомін
>   бога-біди): «Цур дурня серед будня!», «Цур їм та пек!», «Цур тобі,
>   сатано, відчепись!»; пор. у П. Куліша: «Кажуть дивні речі, не знаю, чи
>   вірити тільки: буцім — цур нашого місця — до неї літає змій!».

Answer (score 0):

словник SlangZone подає таке [визначення слова «чур»](https://www.slangzone.net/word/%D0%A7%D1%83%D1%80):

> Чур - бог тепла і затишку, охоронець дому. Тепер деколи вживається як «слово-оберіг», типу «чур, обережи мене від чогось».

Comment: На жаль, це не дуже переконливо, бо, наскільки я розумію, цей словник не має конкретного колективу укладачів/редакторів (на авторитет яких можна було б покластися) і не посилається на інші (старіші) джерела. Тобто він дозволяє нам побачити, що така думка існує, але не допомагає перевірити, наскільки вона вірогідна. Утім, приблизно ту саму версію [висловила Mariia Matskevych](/a/4554) з посиланням на Жайворонка, який своєю чергою послався на Огієнка.

Comment: @Sasha така вже є реальність інтернету, на жаль, більшість словників є погано сконфігуровані, якщо мова йде про SEO, тому люди, котрі шукають якесь конкретне слово часто не можуть знайти визначення й або йдуть геть без жодної інформації, або йдуть на російськи словники.